# Spring MVC 4 controllers not called

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

EDIT: I realized I made a mistake in my `ComponentScan` as a lot of commenters pointed out, I changed it but it is still not working (still 404).

I have a project and I'm using all annotations-based configuration. Here is the configuration files:

`WebConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "src.controller")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

`WebInitializer.java`

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };

    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

I also have a persistence config but I don't think that's relevant to this problem. Anyways, here is my root path controller:

`AuthorController.java`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/authors", "/"})
public class AuthorController {

    @Autowired
    AuthorService authorservice;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAuthors(ModelMap model){
        System.out.println("----------called--------------"); //not printed
        List<Author> authors = authorservice.getAllAuthors();
        model.addAttribute("authors", authors);
        return "authors";
    }
}
```

The controller never gets called and I end up getting a 404 error.

Comment: I doubt your base package is named `src`..

Comment: if your files under `src` then add `basepackage="."` instead

Comment: @AsteriskNinja it's in a package `controller` under the `src` directory, so should it be "src.controller"? many thanks.

Comment: if your package name is controller then put `controller` instead of `src`

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell the name of the package to which 'AuthorController' belongs ? I think issue is with `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "src")`. Here you should add package name of the controller classes.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.sample.app") 

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.sample.*") 

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.*")
```

All the above are valid entries for ComponentScan annotation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the package is called `controller` and it's in the `src` directory. So `ComponentScan` really only needs to scan the package that contains the controllers?

Comment: I changed it to "src.controller" and I'm still getting 404.

Comment: Please try @ComponentScan(basePackages = "controller")  and @ComponentScan(basePackages = "controller.*")

Answer (score 0):

The `basePackages` property of `@ComponentScan` annotation doesn't represent the folder where your java code is. It represents the root package of java classes where Spring should scan for Spring beans.

So, if you have your controllers in `com.myapp.web.controllers` then configure it as follows:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.myapp.web.controllers")
```